# How to pluck a collection while preserving the keys

Tags: laravel

I have following array of data (those are headers returned from laravels Http module):

```
  #items: array:4 [▼
    "X-Page" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "X-Per-Page" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "100"
    ]
    "X-Total" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1116"
    ]
    "X-Total-Pages" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "12"
    ]
  ]
```

I would like to convert it into following array/collection:

```
  #items: array:4 [▼
    "X-Page" => "1"
    "X-Per-Page" => "100"
    "X-Total" => "1116"
    "X-Total-Pages" => "12"
  ]
```

I tried to do it by using `$collection->pluck(0)` but that removed the keys giving me this result:

```
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "100"
    2 => "1116"
    3 => "12"
  ]
```

Is there a way to pluck a collection while preserving original keys?

Comment: well you can't pluck and preserve the keys, because that would not be pluck anymore, however you can filter it using ->filter() function and keep the key/value pair you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection `map` method, it will preserve the keys:

```
$collection->map(function ($item) {
    return $item[0];
});
```

Comment: I am doing it this way, but was hoping for a oneliner with dot format.

Comment: for one-liner you can use the new array funciton syntax: `$data->map(fn ($item) => $item[0]);` No idea for other syntax, sorry